# Pandas rank based on condition

Tags: pandas

I have this column I need to rank based on 'P':

```
             team  GC  GP  Fase   P  SG rank
0   Internacional  18  32     8  36  14  1  
1        Flamengo  29  33     5  35   4  2  
2     Atlético-MG  23  35     5  35  12  3
...
```

This is achieved by:

```
df['rank'] = df['P'].rank(ascending=False)
```

However, sometimes teams will have same number of points, and the one with most SG must be ranked higher.

How do I rank based on this condition?

---

Expected result:

```
             team  GC  GP  Fase   P  SG  rank
0   Internacional  18  32     8  36  14   1 
1     Atlético-MG  23  35     5  35  12   2
2        Flamengo  29  33     5  35   4   3 

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sort_values` with a list of columns to sort by and an equal length list of booleans signifying which to sort ascending

```
df = df.sort_values(['P', 'SG'], ascending=[False, False])
```

If you need a `rank` column, you can derive it from the index
reset the index to get the rank

```
df['rank'] = df.reset_index().index + 1
# set the original index back
df.set_index('index')
```